# date_part or EXTRACT function in Querydsl

Tags: java, postgresql, date, jpql, querydsl

There a way to use date_part or EXTRACT function or  equivalent using querydsl? I'm using spring framework to build a rest aplicaiton with querydsl, and a need to make a group by date interval like

```
QUARTER of the year (SELECT EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40')
```

or

```
SELECT date_part('day', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40')
```

I have been search for a solution using just querydsl but withou success.

I'm using postgreSQL db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice when i get a month or a year of a DataPath type the extract function is used, so i divide by 3 to get a quarter.

Like this, to get the secont part of the year:

```
query.where(classQ.thedate.month().divide(3).ceil().eq(2))
```

Anyway, now i know this is a little dumb question rsrsrs,but maybe help someone